# What to do when there is no explanation about downvotes?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, downvote-reason

I just *answered* a question with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090856/why-curr-and-curr-val-are-the-same-value/38091310#38091310).

First, it got accepted and was ok. Then however, quickly after that I got multiple downvotes, 1 at the beginning (probably because I was a little sloppy with the wording). I then edited it to improve it and asked with a comment under *why?* At which point I noticed I have accumulated 2 more, but still without any sort of feedback.

Now being totally puzzled, what should my next step be?

EDIT:

At the end as a result I have:
+(-1) right after being accepted
+(-2) since asked why in the comments
+(<s>-1</s> -3) since asked here

The timing of the above values may vary. Bet I wouldn't have a singe one if not accepted by OP, or maybe just one. SO is *strange place* to say the least.

Comment: That seems really weird (but I can't judge on the technical accuracy of what you're saying.)

Comment: You could continue editing, or if you feel it'd just be a waste of your time then do nothing. As much as you don't have any other choice but to dwell on it, no point dwelling on it. Read the other answers maybe and see if they contradict yours and consider if your answer might in fact be inaccurate. Sucks that your answer is accepted so you can't delete it if you wanted to, though.

Comment: I think you can use [the other upvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38091588/1038015) as feedback. The text you quote in your answer even says what you're failing to address i.e. "suitably converted"

Comment: @RobertLongson I saw "suitably converted" and thought about his implicit UB. But also thought that it was more important for him to **actually answer** his question. Furthermore, UB was already pointed out all over the place.

Comment: Why not do both, i.e answer his question **and** point out the UB then?

Comment: "UB was already pointed out all over the place." and now being stubborn I don't want. But you do have right.

Comment: Your __all-bold edit__ doesn't really help the answer I don't think.

Comment: Sorry, I know, but I had enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right there on the downvote arrow it says for answers: "This answer is not useful". Thats all explaination that is given, and all that is needed.

Comments asking for downvotes to be explained are usually seen unfavorably by the community and lead to further downvotes.

Considering the answer is properly formatted, the reason that I think lead to it is that you're advocating sloppy coding. In essence you're glossing over the fact that OP is invoking some undefined behavior. Since OP is clearly a beginner, you shouldn't give them an easy way out to hold on to their bad habits in coding.

But asides from the technical merits of your answer, if you don't want to change it a bunch, you should just leave it alone. 4 downvotes aren't a big deal, and fratting about it too much is likely counterproductive.

Comment: Every time the tooltip is brought up I have to wonder - how often has anyone found the statement "This answer is not useful" (with an implicit full stop) useful by itself? You'd still have to think about all the possible ways an answer could be useful or not useful, and try to guess your way out of them. Sometimes it does result in a better answer regardless - other times it just ends up being a waste of time.

Comment: @BoltClock I did some times, because it illustrates to me that downvotes aren't that big of a deal. Oh whoo, so this wasn't useful to someone, so unless they point out a flaw in the post in the comments, or unless I find one relatively quickly, I tend to just move on when one of my posts is downvoted.

Comment: That's a good way of thinking about it.

Comment: I don't think downvotes always indicates not useful, it can be just because the author asks the downvote reasons, to be honest, in my experience, the downvote tips are almost useless to give clues to improve the answer as the meaning of the tip is too broad